# Excel VBA Activate method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that I used in a different macro and wotked that now is not working and I keep getting run time error 1004 in the line with activate:

```
Sub initialize()

dim MonthName  as string
dim MainWB  as workbook
dim VisualWS as worksheet

MonthName = cells (1,1).value
Set MainWB = ThisWorkbook
Set VisualWS = MainWB.Worksheets("Visual")

With VisualWS
    .Range("L1:W1").Find(MonthName, , xlValues, xlWhole).Activate
End With

MonthCol = ActiveCell.Column

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you manually find the requested cell?

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs on Range.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel), the "method returns `Nothing` if no match is found."

Most likely, your .Range().Find() method isn't finding any matches and therefore returns `Nothing`, which doesn't have a function `Activate`.

Try this instead:

```
Dim findResult As Range
Set findResult = .Range("L1:W1").Find(MonthName, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If findResult <> Nothing then findResult.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

`Find` might well return `Nothing`, so I would rather write:

```
With VisualWS
    set target = .Range("L1:W1").Find(MonthName, , xlValues, xlWhole)
End With
If target is Nothing Then 
    DoSomething
else
    MonthCol = target.Cells(1,1).Column
End if
```

Comment: [False](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-activate-method-excel) - Activate marks a single cell within a selection as active.

Comment: Seriously? You literally just removed your previous (**wrong**) answer and replaced it with what I already posted!?

Comment: @E.Villiger Did not see you stuff before I fixed mine. But thanks for the -1 :-)

Comment: If you had some character you would just remove your duplicate answer. (Btw, the -1 was for the answer being wrong, that was before it was a duplicate)